# Highchart's selection-function updating with delay

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm struggling with Highchart's event functions right now.

I want to create the range-selector, so when I select a new area in my chart, I want the min-data and max-data to be saved.

I want to save them in variables in my scope:

```
$scope.from
```

My function:

```
$scope.ChartOptions = function ChartOptions() {
    return {
        options: {
            chart: {
                events:  {
                    selection: function(){
                        $scope.from = moment(this.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min);
                    }
                },
                zoomType: 'x'
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ..  
}
```

This one works, but not immediately! It´s updating, when I do another action like pressing a dropdown-menu in my page.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Is there a better functionality than the selection -function of Highcharts/Highstock?

Or can someone tell me how the already existing range-selector is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `$evalAsync();`, like:

```
             ...
                selection: function(){
                    $scope.from = moment(this.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min);
                    $scope.$evalAsync();
                }
             ...
```

Which will run a digest cycle only if there's no digest cycle running already.

Of course this is assuming that you made sure the selection function is called in the right time, and it's just the effect in the UI that's not happening.